# Smart syntax for this issue

Tags: python

I have list of lists. Let say somethink like that:

```
somelist = [ 
               [1, 2, 3],
               [4, 8, 2],
               [7, 8, 4, 8, 2],
           ]
```

Here my list contains 3 lists. With list which have `len(list) == 3` I want to do something like this:

```
list1 = somelist[0]
list2 = somelist[1]
list3 = somelist[2]

for l1 in list1:
    for l2 in list2:
        for l3 in list3:
            function(something=[l1, l2, l3])
```

But my list can have `2 <= len(somelist) <= 10`. So if my list have `len(somelist) == 4` I have to do:

```
list1 = somelist[0]
list2 = somelist[1]
list3 = somelist[2]
list4 = somelist[3]

for l1 in list1:
    for l2 in list2:
        for l3 in list3:
            for l4 in list4:
                function(something=[l1, l2, l3, l4])
```

So my question is how to write nice code which will work with different `len(somelist)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thing you need [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
import itertools
for s in itertools.product(*somelist):
    function(something=s)
```

*----Flat is better than nested.*

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to do it *recursively* and each time *expand* the list items the `*args` way with [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).